# How to give url path in spring boot refer to local file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, war

I am trying to consume the WSDL file in the spring boot application, WSDL file is placed into the `src/main/resource/wsdl/file.wsdl`.

*Project structure:*

[image]

*Code:*

```java
static {
   URL url = null;
   try {            
      url = new URL("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/wsdl/outbound.wsdl");
   } catch(IOException e) { 
      java.util.logging.Logger
            .getLogger(OutboundService.class.getName())
            .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO,
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", 
                 "file:/D:/ERPLOGIC/ERPProjects/JAVA/mavenproject/eclipse-workspace/topconpoc/src/main/resources/wsdl/outbound.wsdl");
   }
   WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

It works fine in locally, but when deployed in the AWS server as a war file, it does not work.

What is the proper to refer to the path in the Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("wsdl/outbound.wsdl");
```

This should work

Comment: When I use    url = new URL("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/wsdl/outbound.wsdl");  it works fine while start app using spring too suite. but convert this into warfile and deployed in tomcat server it gives result like this  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\src\main\resources\wsdl\outbound.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Thank you it works - I made code like this

Comment: thank you for your code, finally resolved  and I used the following code                                 
                                                                                                                                    
        String resourceName = "wsdl/outbound.wsdl";
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        url = classLoader.getResource(resourceName);

Answer (score 0):

The file is placed inside the Java resources directory `src/main/resource` and should be loaded from there in all cases. The reason it's not loading properly when deployed is that file is not in that location once packaged. Use the class to locate the resource file from the packaged Java app. This should work both locally and when deployed. Make sure to replace `ClassFileWhereCodeLives` with the class the static code block is inside of.

```java
url = ClassFileWhereCodeLives.class.getResource("/wsdl/outbound.wsdl")
```

Comment: it gives error when run locally java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\wsdl\outbound.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: replaced code like this    static {
        URL url = null;
        // url = new URL("file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/wsdl/outbound.wsdl");
  url = OutboundService.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/wsdl/outbound.wsdl");
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

Comment: @SMugunthankumar sorry I had the `.getClassLoader()` which shouldn't have been there. I've updated the answer without it, try that and it should work. I just confirmed with a sample application locally.

Comment: After updating the code as you said it still gives the same error  java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\wsdl\outbound.wsdl (The system cannot find the path specified)  my wsdl file is in project resource directory

Comment: Even this answer will work if you remove beginning `/` from path.  If you mention path like this `wsdl/outbound.wsdl`